# Thunderbird disconnecting from Dovecot

Tags: email, email-server, dovecot, pop3, thunderbird

I'm managing a Dovecot POP3 server which serves large number of users. Some of these users are in remote locations. I'm getting reports about users whose Thunderbird clients show the number of mails to be downloaded, but disconnects after that.

Server logs shows no corruption about user mailboxes. Only abnormality is only 1 RETR is received, ~10KB of data sent as a reply, nothing downloaded, nothing deleted. Also these users "Disconnect" instead of "Logging out". I cannot find any pointers to my problems. Network connection seems good, server is handling rest of the users with no problems and blazing speed, server hardware is not saturated. I cannot troubleshoot Thunderbird though. I'm just not experienced with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try logging a session with wireshark to check for network problems (rst, ...). Maybe you could try using pop3s instead of pop3 as a broken router/antivirus/... could potentially corrupt a connection.

Comment: While I had no time to diagnose the way you suggested, issue solved itself. I touched nothing on the server, so it was probably the connection either on the remote location or in between. Btw, all communication is POP3s already.